# include external php file into zend framwork

Tags: php

i want to include external php file into my zend project but i can't manage to do this. i place my external file in **public** folder of zend project.  below is what i am trying.

```
require_once (Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl().'/myfile/include/phpfile.php');
```

but i got the following error.

```
( ! ) Warning: require_once(/myproject/public/myfile/include/phpfile.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

`getBaseUrl()` is used for calculating the URL to use in route matches and not for calculating the server path:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.controller.request.html#zend.controller.request.http.baseurl

Assuming your application folder is at the same level as your public folder the following should work for you to get the path of your phpfile.php:

```
$path = realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/myfile/include/phpfile.php')
```

This assumes you have a standard index.php setup complete with the APPLICATION_PATH constant.

You can then require the $path variable:

```
require_once($path);
```

However you should also consider whether it is prudent to use require on any public paths, the php file would likely be better placed outside the /public path for security reasons.